# Преобразование переменной float в int и наоборот

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть очень простой код (калькулятор), в котором есть переменная 'oper', которая просит ввод от пользователя (ввести нужно операцию (+, -, /, * или %)), есть переменные n1 и n2 (преобразованные в float, если их в int, то при вводе дробного числа будет ошибка), которые просят от пользователя ввод первого и второго числа,  и  есть условия по типу

```
if oper == "+":
    result = n1 + n2
    print("Result:" + result)
```

И так с остальными операциями.

Дело в том, что если в n1 и n2 ввести целые числа, то в результате программа напишет их с точкой в конце. Можно как-то сделать, чтобы результат выводился целым числом, если происходит операция с целыми числами, а не с дробными?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого достаточно правильно преобразовать введенное пользователем число в `int` или `float`.

Я бы сделал это так:

```
def to_number(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return float(x)
```

Тесты:

```
In [28]: to_number("3.14")
Out[28]: 3.14

In [29]: to_number("3")
Out[29]: 3

In [30]: to_number("XXX")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-d41acd007258> in to_number(x)
      2     try:
----> 3         return int(x)
      4     except ValueError:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'XXX'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-88249f252567> in <module>
----> 1 to_number("XXX")

<ipython-input-27-d41acd007258> in to_number(x)
      3         return int(x)
      4     except ValueError:
----> 5         return float(x)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'XXX'
```